# Passing more than 10 parameters between classes in C#?

Tags: c#

I am a new to C#, I need a small help on how can I pass multiple parameters between the classes?
Below is a small example but my parameters will more than the 10. Is there another way to this?

```
public StreamStructure(String name, string id, string classname, int number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.classname = classname;
        this.number = number;
    }
```

List ------

```
List<abc> don = new List<abc>();
            foreach (XmlElement abc_cdb in abc_cdbs)
            {

                abc.Name = abc_cdb.GetAttribute("NAME");
                abc.Id = abc_cdb.GetAttribute("id");
                abc.Clssname = abc_cdb.GetAttribute("classname");
                abc.number = Convert.ToInt32(abc_cdb.GetAttribute("number"));
                don.Add(abc);


               }
```

I have used as suggested in ans but I am trying to create a list in C# my first record gets replaced with the 2nd one, since the fields in MyDTO are defined as public. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using [C# Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) or a [Data Transfer Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) than a large number of constructor parameters.  Or combine the two.

```
public class MyDTO
{
   String Name { get; set; }
   String Id { get; set; }
   String ClassName { get; set; }
   int Number { get; set; }
}

var MyDTO = new MyDTO() 
{
   Name      = Name,
   Id        = Id,
   ClassName = ClassName,
   Number    = Number
}

var stream = new StreamStructure(MyDTO)
```

To create a list of these objects as in your example, create a new DTO within the loop body.

```
var don = new List<MyDTO>(); 
foreach (XmlElement abc_cdb in abc_cdbs) 
{
    var abc = new MyDTO()
    {
        Name = abc_cdb.GetAttribute("NAME");
        Id = abc_cdb.GetAttribute("id");
        ClassName = abc_cdb.GetAttribute("classname");
        Number = Convert.ToInt32(abc_cdb.GetAttribute("number"));
    };

    don.Add( abc );
}
```

Comment: I have used as suggested above but I am trying ti create a list in C# my first record gets replaced with the 2nd one, since the fields in MyDTO are defined as public. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to create a new DTO at each iteration within your loop body. Updated the answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use DTO's (data transfer objects). That is, create a class that has all the fields you want to send and use an instance of it as a parameter. Added bonus is that your method signature won't change even if you change your DTO class.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a domain object that represents the item you are manipulating.

```
    public class Widget
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public string ClassName {get;set;}
        public int Number {get;set;}
    }

    var myWidget = new Widget();
    myWidget.Name = "Blue Widget";
    //etc

    StreamStructure(myWidget);
```

Comment: Yes I tries this, but if I am trying to make a list this value gets override with the new data. suppose my records are - name - aaaa, id - erd, classname - 10c, number - 15 and 2nd record is don, werd, 12c, 100...After writing the first record the  when I add second record in the list the first record will replaced by the 2nd one .

Comment: Not sure I understand that - what do you mean by "trying to make a list"?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a new class that contains the properties you want to pass to the method, and change your method to include just that new class.

For your example, write a new class like this:

```
public class RequestObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your method like this:

```
public StreamStructure(RequestObject requestObject)
{
    //DoStuff
}
```